# Best way to find and match two integers from different arrays in swift 3? (Multidimensional Array)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach, swift3

In Swift 3 i have two multi dimensional arrays named json and json2 that gets some code from an api. I then do an for each on the first array, and for each value inside that array i loop over array 2 to find matches, this seems like a really bad way of doing this, i was hoping for an alternative way that's probally quicker?

Heres my code:

```
var json:[[String:Any]] = []
var json2:[[String:Any]] = []

            for each in self.json {


                for each2 in self.json2 {

                    if(each["PrePaidCoffeeCardId"]! as! Int == each2["id"]! as! Int)
                    {
                       print(each2["coffeeBrandId"]! as! Int)
                    }

                }

            }
```

this returns the output in the console:

```
2
2
3
```

this is the values i want to get, but the approach of getting them seems to take alot of power, i was hoping for an easier solution?

Comment: Strictly spoken an array containing dictionaries is not a multidimensional array. The object oriented way is to map the dictionary to a custom struct or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have large numbers of prepaid cards, you will get good performance by building a temporary index using a dictionary :

```
var cardBrands:[Int:[Int]] = [:]
json2.map{ ($0["id"]! as! Int, $0["coffeeBrandId"]! as! Int)  }
     .forEach{ cardBrands[$0] = [$1] + (cardBrands[$0] ?? Array<Int>())  }

let brandIds = json.flatMap{ cardBrands[ $0["PrePaidCoffeeCardId"]! as! Int]! }
```

The cardBrands dictionary is setup only once, and returns the list of coffeeBrandIds of each card id.  Because of the dictionary's internal indexing it will provide much faster results than iterating through the json2 array.  This will give you roughly N+M processing time instead of N*M.